# elasticsearchtemplate dosearch method issue

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-commons, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use spring-elastic search template for the queries.

I am getting below exception when i try to execute queries through elastic search template.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [home] in context with path [/grid-admin-service] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(Ljava/util/Collection;)Z] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.doSearch(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:589)
```

There is no `isNotEmpty` method in `CollectionUtils class`.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a version mismatch of the commons collections jar.
I fixed it by giving the latest dependency in pom.xml